# How can I get the jobs that are in execution in a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, scheduled-tasks

I need to force the release of resources when a task is interrupted. For that, I implemented [this solution](http://java.ggarciao.com/2011/08/how-to-release-resources-from.html). But with this, when I call `shutdown()` all the task in the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.getQueue()` are forced correctly, but some of my jobs kept the resources. I checked very well the behavior and I figured out this: when a task is in execution, he is not present in the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` queue (I know it sounds obvious). The problem is that I need to force the release of resources for all the jobs (in the queue or in execution)

So, How can I get the jobs that are in execution? Do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can maintain a list of all the Future's you create when you submit the jobs.
Use this list to cancel all futures.

Comment: This is actually our current implementation, but with that solution we keep a reference to all the scheduled jobs (even the executed ones). So, the list of references grows a lot with tasks that no need to be processed and they will be in memory until scheduler shutdown. This will cause problem with garbage collection don't you think?

Comment: It might do, however you only need to keep the last N futures. You can cancel/discard Futures after a certain point. If the system gets too far behind you have an issue which more complex to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want to call

```
executor.shutdownNow()
```

that will attempt to cancel currently running tasks (using `Thread.interrupt` so you'll need to implement an 'interruption policy' in each task that uses the interrupt flag).

from the javadoc

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.
>
> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt, so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

This will return a list of waiting tasks, so you can always put this back onto a 'wait list' rather than loose them completely. You might also want follow that up with an 'await termination' to avoid run away code. For example, `executor.awaitTermination(...)`.

[tempus-fugit](http://tempusfugitlibrary.org/) has some handy classes for handling this. You just call

```
shutdown(executor).waitingForShutdown(millis(400));
```

see [here](https://github.com/tobyweston/tempus-fugit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/code/tempusfugit/concurrency/ExecutorServiceShutdown.java) for details.

Also, the solution you outline in the blog post; I'm not sure if that's quite right. `Future.cancel` will only stop the task from being scheduled. If you were to update the example in the blog to allow interruption (ie `cancel(true)`, it'd be equivalent (more or less) with the `shutdownNow`. That is to say, it will call `interrupt` on the underlying task which (if you've implemented an interruption policy) will stop it processing. As for cleaning up after interruption, you just need to make sure that you handle that appropriately within the interruption policy implementation. The upshot is that I think you can cancel *and* cleanup correctly using shutdownNow (or cancel(true))

Comment: But the `shutdownNow()` method doesn't call the `Future.cancel()` of the scheduled jobs. Actually, it uses a private `Worker` List to interrupt the threads with the `Thread.interrupt()` method. So, my decorators aren't invoked with the `shutdownNow()` method. In other hand, you're right: the `shutdown()` method will call the `Future.cancel(false)` without interrupting the thread. So what we actually do is to release the resources when the param `mayInterruptIfRunning = true` and we overwrite the `shutdownNow()` to call the `Future.cancel(true)` before calling `super.shutdownNow()`.

Comment: The question is: Which jobs list I must use in my custom `shutdownNow()` method to force correctly all the jobs? If I use the `getQueue()` method I will get the scheduled and periodicals ones (and this list may be empty if `shutdown()` is called before). But what about the thread that are actually running? The `shutdownNow()` will interrupt them, but how can I force them to release theirs resources? I need a reference to them in order to call the `Future.cancel(true)` and for that I keep a list as suggested in other answer. I don't know if this is the best way to do it

Comment: I guess I'm saying why call cancel at all? What's the difference you see here than with interrupt? Ie. if you can release resources on interrupt, you may not need a custom cancel. I think exploring *not* using cancel more might be worth while...

Comment: When you interrupt a thread with `Thread.interrupt()` there is no callback method that allows do something before/after the interruption (for example, release of resources). I mean, when a thread is interrupted, it might finish his `run()` method, or it might not and no before() or after() methods are called in the Runnable object. But if you decorate your task with FutureSchedule you can capture an "event" that happens before/after the `Thread.interrupt()` (the famous `Future.cancel()`) and then there you can release the resources. How can you implement this without calling `Future.cancel()`?

Comment: Are you talking about interrupting a thread you yourself didn't create? I'm coming from the angle of interrupting a thread you wrote yourself, in which case, you'd be able to deal with the interrupt (& release resources). ie, you'd code it such. If its not your thread, I can't say how it'll deal with interrupt (the 'interruption policy' I was banging on about). You'd have to share the thread source I guess...

Comment: Lets me see if I'm missing something: When implementing a Runnable the developer must implement the run() method. Also, the only method that the "thread container" will call it is the run() method, right? So, if I will implement an interruption policy I must implement it in the run() method (like checking an interruption flag or with a finally block). So, my policy will work only and only if the run() method executes all the sentences of the "interruption policy". Now the problem is: what to do if the run() method doesn't execute; for example, the finally block due to a thread interruption?

Comment: Perhaps we should put some samples together to make sure we're talking about the same thing, I'm a little lost now! It may not be helpful and at the risk of sounding like a broken record... you're right; the interruption policy will be in the run. If run isn't called, your thread won't be running. It is impossible for finally not to be called (I say 'impossible'; system.exit and daemon threads can bypass it). So normally, you can do something like http://www.smipple.net/snippet/bad.robot/Thread%20Misc and be sure finally is called, whatever. is that what we're talking about?!

Comment: Yes!!! But ... In your example: Lets say that the thread is running, and the it is `doSomethingInteresting()`, and then, the thread is interrupted. In a perfect world, your `while` loop will end and the finally block will `cleanup()`. But I have the weirdest case ever: I interrupt the thread, and the finally block is never reached!! So, the `cleanup()` is not executed. Very weird right? But actually, the java specification doesn't assure the finally block execution after a thread interruption (Read [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html))

Comment: It happens in our CentOS environment, but in Windows and other unix-based OS works as you (and I) expected.

Comment: that really is weird! :) I just don't get it; that quote from the oracle docs is very odd. I mean, interruption is only applicable to things that check the interrupt flag. I just can't see how its possible! I know on vm exit or if the thread is a daemon, it could skip the finally but I've never seen it do so otherwise. It sounds like a CentOS thing from what you say but I really have no clue at this point! Good to discover something new and interesting though so thanks for posting :)